# Variables in GUI application not updating

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am currently making a very simple Java GUI application, but have run into the problem that my variables are unable to update. The application is a simple basketball scorekeeper and the score integers do not update nor does the text of the labels showing them. There are no errors so I am unsure as of why nothing is updating. The code:

ScoreWindow.java

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ScoreWindow implements ScoreListener {

    private JFrame frmScorewindow;

    public volatile JLabel homeScoreLabel;

    public JLabel awayScoreLabel;

    public volatile int homeScore, awayScore;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ScoreWindow window = new ScoreWindow();
                    window.frmScorewindow.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ScoreWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        // Init Scores
        homeScore = 0;
        awayScore = 0;

        frmScorewindow = new JFrame();
        frmScorewindow.setResizable(false);
        frmScorewindow.setTitle("Score Keeper");
        frmScorewindow.setBounds(100, 100, 551, 348);
        frmScorewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton homeScore2 = new JButton("+2");
        homeScore2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ScoreListener listener = new ScoreWindow();
                listener.homeScore(2);
            }
        });
        homeScore2.setBounds(110, 129, 117, 29);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(homeScore2);

        JButton homeScore3 = new JButton("+3");
        homeScore3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ScoreListener listener = new ScoreWindow();
                listener.homeScore(3);
            }
        });
        homeScore3.setBounds(110, 156, 117, 29);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(homeScore3);

        JButton awayScore2 = new JButton("+2");
        awayScore2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ScoreListener listener = new ScoreWindow();
                listener.awayScore(2);
            }
        });
        awayScore2.setBounds(332, 129, 117, 29);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(awayScore2);

        JButton awayScore3 = new JButton("+3");
        awayScore3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ScoreListener listener = new ScoreWindow();
                listener.awayScore(3);
            }
        });
        awayScore3.setBounds(332, 156, 117, 29);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(awayScore3);

        JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ScoreListener listener = new ScoreWindow();
                listener.reset();
            }
        });
        resetButton.setBounds(225, 220, 117, 29);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(resetButton);

        homeScoreLabel = new JLabel("000");
        homeScoreLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        homeScoreLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        homeScoreLabel.setBounds(138, 88, 61, 29);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(homeScoreLabel);

        awayScoreLabel = new JLabel("000");
        awayScoreLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        awayScoreLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        awayScoreLabel.setBounds(361, 88, 61, 29);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(awayScoreLabel);

        JLabel lblHome = new JLabel("Home");
        lblHome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblHome.setBounds(138, 60, 61, 16);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(lblHome);

        JLabel lblAway = new JLabel("Away");
        lblAway.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblAway.setBounds(361, 60, 61, 16);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(lblAway);

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Score Keeper App");
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        title.setBounds(180, 33, 200, 16);
        frmScorewindow.getContentPane().add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        print("reset();");
        homeScore = 0;
        awayScore = 0;
        awayScoreLabel.setText("" + awayScore);
        homeScoreLabel.setText("" + homeScore);
    }

    @Override
    public void awayScore(int n) {
        print("awayScore();");
        awayScore+=n;
        awayScoreLabel.setText("" + awayScore);
    }

    @Override
    public void homeScore(int n) {
            print("homeScore();");
            print(homeScoreLabel.getText());
            homeScore = homeScore + n;
            homeScoreLabel.setText("" + homeScore);
            homeScoreLabel.repaint();
            homeScoreLabel.revalidate();
    }

    static void print(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

ScoreListener.java

```
public interface ScoreListener {
        public void reset();
        public void awayScore(int n);
        public void homeScore(int n);
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You're calling methods on the wrong ScoreWindow instance. You're creating new ScoreWindow instances within your listener, but these instances are not the one displayed, and so the display will never change. Be careful what references you're using as that's the key here.

Comment: So to be sure you're not doing this, make sure that you see `new ScoreWindow()` only once in the entire program, not 15 times like you're doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ScoreWindow window = new ScoreWindow();
                window.frmScorewindow.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

You create your window with the above code.

```
    JButton homeScore2 = new JButton("+2");
    homeScore2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ScoreListener listener = new ScoreWindow();
            listener.homeScore(2);
        }
    });
```

But then you create a second instance of the window.

Don't do this. You only need to create once instance of your class. All other code to reference this instance.

Your ActionListner class is defined in the ScoreWindow class you you can just reference the "homeScore()" method directly.